# Where does bus 111 leave from MCO?

Tags: buses, orlando

I will be in Orlando next weekend for a conference. I don't drive, so I was hoping to take the bus over to International Drive from the airport. The 111 bus seems like the best option, but I wasn't able to find out where it leaves from the airport. I don't want to be running around the airport trying to find the bus. Does anybody know where at the airport the bus stops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the Orlando Airport website](https://www.orlandoairports.net/parking-transportation/), the local bus stop is

> Located at Terminal A on Level 1 (Ground Transportation) in spaces A38-A41

(see the "Local Bus" tab.)  The location is shown on [this map](https://orlandoairports.net/getting-around-mco/#terminal-maps);  the exact location of "spaces A38–A41" is not indicated, but if you go to Level 1 of Terminal A I suspect it will be easy enough to find from there.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I was looking a the transit agency website. It hadn't occurred to me to check the airport's website.

Comment: @AndrewRay: It's pretty easy to forget that airports have websites, but most of them do and some of them are actually useful.